# Submit a form created in a popup window

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a page where I create a popup. On the popup created, I click on a radio button created on the popup and on click of a button I need to submit the form and pass the radio button value using post method to a new page. How can I achieve this using jquery or javascript?

Comment: What sort of popup are you using? A modal dialog, an iFrame, an alert?

Comment: one alternative is to use custom jquery-ui dialogs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using AJAX:

**Reference**: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "post_page.php",
  data: { radio: $("radio_btn").val() }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert("Done!");
});
```